# "the" before general concepts

Tags: articles

Take a look at these two sentences:

> There are problems for students living away from **the family**.
>
> Computers play a very important role in **education** nowadays.

Comparing them, I wonder why in the second one, 'education' is not preceded by 'the'.

Comment: Actually, the first one looks strange. _Their_ instead of _the_ sounds much more natural.

Answer (score 4):

In your first sentence, "family" is a [countable noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun) - that is, you can have a *specific number* of families. "Education", on the other hand, is an abstract concept and isn't countable (the concept of "one education" makes no sense).

Because of this, "the" is used in your first sentence to indicate that students are living away from *their specific* families. If "family" were to be replaced with another abstract uncountable noun (for example "friendship"), you would drop "the" in that sentence as well.

Comment: I agree, but note that "family" can also be used as an uncountable noun. "Family is very important to us."

Comment: What Jay said. Also, "a good education" is a common phrase.

Comment: @Damkerng True enough - I don't think that makes it a countable noun though. "Two educations" is an absurd phrase, but "two families" isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest that "the" is unnecessary in the first sentence, which solves the problem.

Saying "the family" in the first sentence implies one specific family, but doesn't use the possessive pronoun "their" as expected. That makes it sound like a specific family that isn't that of the student - this makes it sound like a reference to the mafia, or a cult :)

I'd instead recommend saying:

> There are problems for students living away from family.

This makes *family* a more general/abstract noun or idea, like *education* is in the 2nd sentence. Neither requires "the" since it doesn't specifically identify one family or one education.

Alternatively:

> There are problems for students living away from *their* families.

This specifically refers to the student's own family, using the correct possessive pronoun.