# Article the for general noun

Tags: grammar, articles

I read somewhere that we have to use article "the" for general type nouns in general concepts for example:

We don't know the effects of such chemicals on *the* body.

here body is a general type.

which one of these sentences are correct and why?

- Computers play a very important role in education nowadays.
- Computers play a very important role in *the* education nowadays.

Comment: If the noun can be non-count  ("education") then we don't use the definite article to refer to it in general terms.  "A quiet place is good for *meditation*".  In contrast, "After medical school, his specialty was *the heart*".

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [“the” before general concepts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33088/)

Answer (score 1):

In the cases of your usage

> Computers play a very important role **in education** nowadays.

is correct, *education* is a general noun, however

> Computers play a very important role **in** ***the*** **education** nowadays.

is more specific and would need to be qualified

> Computers play a very important role in **the** education *of children* nowadays.

also acceptable might be

> Computers play a very important role **in education** *of children* nowadays.

Comment: Yeh, it's basically the same as "**education**" in general or some specific education. This works with any non-count noun.